# Get IntelliJ or SBT to give two names to a package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Please tell me a more describing title :P

I have an SBT project in IntelliJ and its `src` directory constructed like:

```
src/main/scala/package1/AAA.scala
src/main/scala/package1/BBB.scala
src/main/scala/package2/CCC.scala
src/main/scala/...
```

So now these classes are imported like:

```
import package1.AAA._
```

But actually I want to import these classes like:

```
import org.myname.package1.AAA._
```

At the moment I have two ways; one is to put `org.myname` to all the class files' `package` attributes like:

```
package org.myname.package1
class AAA {...
```

which works, but doing this manually is time consuming, and makes things complicated.

Another one is to reformat the directories like:

```
src/main/scala/org/myname/package1/AAA.scala
src/main/scala/org/myname/package1/BBB.scala
src/main/scala/org/myname/package2/CCC.scala
src/main/scala/org/myname/...
```

which works too, but I'd not like to make the looking of the structure like this.

Is there an automatic way to include all classes into `org.myname` without changing the structure, with the SBT or IntelliJ features?

Comment: You can refactor each class, which will correct all of the imports for you as well.  However, it will be only one class at a time.

Comment: @joescii Yes, it's only for each class. I want to somehow make it always happen.

Comment: @RyoichiroOka You can select multiple classes in the project pane, on which you want to perform the refactoring, and press F6 to refactor all of them at once. Same is true for packages.

Comment: @joescii it's good to know :) thanks, but still, I want to have something automatic that does the stuff for me, like each time I make a new source file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new package named `org.myname`.
2. Move the `package1` inside `org.myname`
3. Move `package2` inside `org.myname`

IntellIJ IDEA will fix everything for you.

Comment: Yes, this is the second way I listed in the question. The thing I don't like about this method is that the structure is going to be looking weird. I edited the question so it's not gonna make people misunderstand it

Comment: "structure is going to be looking weird" what you mean?

Comment: I mean, let me say you're now in the `scala` dir, then there's nothing but the `org` dir, so you go into the dir, then there's nothing but the `myname` dir, and finally you can see things under the `myname` dir.

Comment: It's how packages works in Java (and Scala too i think) package name should be the same as directory tree. In IntelliJ IDEA you will not see there empty directory. They will be merged.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno that is true for java, but not Scala.  It doesn't care what the package is, how many names are defined, or anything like that.